# find row before rows with same values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  peak-date  
0    17 Jan  
1    17 Jan  
2    31 Mar  
3    30 Apr  
4    31 May  
5    26 Jun  
6    26 Jun
```

I want to find the row before the row when peak-date values become the same. In this case that would be the row with `peak-date` of `31 May`. I can do this fo r numeric values using df['peak-date'].diff(), but how do I do it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way might be as following: 
First you can read the string in date format using `to_datetime` in dataframe and find difference between each row with `diff` function. In addition, we can find difference in seconds so that there is floating number. Then, shifting difference row by 2 up, and searching for first occurrence of 0 difference would give the `peak-date` value.

```
# read csv for date with month day
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

# Convert to datetime with difference in days
df['diff'] = pd.to_datetime(df['peak-date'], format='%d %b').diff()

# save difference in seconds in different column and shift by 2
df['diff_seconds'] = df['diff'].apply(lambda row: row.total_seconds())
df['diff_seconds'] = df['diff_seconds'].shift(-2)
```

View `dataframe`:

```
  peak-date    diff  diff_seconds
0    17 Jan     NaT     6307200.0
1    17 Jan  0 days     2592000.0
2    31 Mar 73 days     2678400.0
3    30 Apr 30 days     2246400.0
4    31 May 31 days           0.0
5    26 Jun 26 days     2592000.0
6    26 Jun  0 days     2246400.0
6    26 Jul 30 days           0.0
6    21 Aug 26 days           NaN
6    21 Aug  0 days           NaN
```

Now get the value before for first consecutive date:

```
# look for the first occurence index and get the row by index
first_occur_index = df.diff_seconds.eq(0.0).idxmax()
df.iloc[first_occur_index]['peak-date']
```

Result:

```
'31 May'
```